# How can I align my items two items per row using flexbox?

Tags: css, sass, flexbox, jsx

I want to align my flex items (two items per row) 
This image show what I want  : 
https://ibb.co/rFLXP5P
and this is what I did (my result for now) : 
https://ibb.co/yB3Sftv
I want them two items in the center per row , as the two first rows ( search case and the button case).
here's my code.
JSX code :

```
 render() {
    return <div className="employees-container">
      <div className='employee-search'>
          <label for="name">Search Employees</label>
          <input placeholder='Name...' onChange={(e) => this.setState({ name: e.target.value })} id="name"/>
      </div>
      <Link to="/add/employee">Add Employee</Link>

        {this.state.employees
          .filter(x => new RegExp(this.state.name, 'i').test(x.name))
          .map(x=><EmployeeCard data={x}></EmployeeCard>)
        }

    </div>;
  }
```

Sass code :

```
.employees-container{
  display: flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  }
  >*{ 
    height: 70px;
    margin:5px;
    width:300px!important;
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Thanks man I edit it

Answer (score 0):

Suppose this is your render structure

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
</div>
```

and CSS

```
.item {
  width: 100%
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container>div {
  flex: 0 50%;
  /*demo*/
  border: red solid;
  box-sizing:border-box
}
```

No match these properties whit your own code may be that will help you

Comment: Hi , didn't work my friend look what i've got : 
https://ibb.co/LZcGG2C

Comment: @BelhediRafaa now check i updated my ans use `flex: 0 50%;` instead of `width:50%`

Comment: can you provide me a render html? form inspector?

Comment: it showed above my friend isn't ? render function (jsx code)

Comment: I updated my code may be that will help you as i didn't get your html code by the code you provided. My bad